# QSplitterHandle grabeMouse won't move handle in Qt6

Tags: qt, qt5, qt6

For my current project I am creating a Blender-like window management.
For testing, I'm trying to drag the splitter after clicking on a label.

To do this, when a `mousePressEvent` occurs on my label, I call `grabMouse()` on my splitter handle. Unfortunately it does not work, my handle won't move even though `mouseMoveEvent()` is called.

The funny thing is that it works perfectly with Qt 5.15.

Am I missing something new about Qt6 ?

I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04. I tried with Qt 6.2 and Qt 6.4.

My code looks like this.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Window.hxx"

class Handle : public QSplitterHandle
{
public:
    Handle(Qt::Orientation orientation, QSplitter *parent)
        : QSplitterHandle(orientation, parent)
    {
        setStyleSheet("QSplitterHandle { background-color : blue; }");
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        printf("mouseMoveEvent\n");
        QSplitterHandle::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        printf("mouseReleaseEvent\n");
        QSplitterHandle::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
        releaseMouse();
    }
};

class Splitter : public QSplitter
{
public:
    Splitter(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QSplitter(parent)
    {
        setHandleWidth(10);
    }

    QSplitterHandle *createHandle() override
    {
        return new Handle(orientation(), this);
    }
};

class Label : public QLabel
{
public:
    Label(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QLabel(text, parent)
    {
        setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : white; }");
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            QSplitter *splitter = qobject_cast<QSplitter *>(parentWidget());
            event->accept();
            printf("oh hi Mark\n");
            splitter->handle(1)->grabMouse();
        }

    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found why.

Since Qt 6.2, they applied this commit.
https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/41726a90e10b1705427dde8ad5a4181be6300309

Before Qt 6.2:

```
void QSplitterHandle::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    Q_D(QSplitterHandle);
    if (!(e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
        return;
    int pos = d->pick(parentWidget()->mapFromGlobal(e->globalPosition().toPoint()))
                 - d->mouseOffset;
    if (opaqueResize()) {
        moveSplitter(pos);
    } else {
        d->s->setRubberBand(closestLegalPosition(pos));
    }
}
```

Since Qt 6.2:

```
void QSplitterHandle::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    Q_D(QSplitterHandle);
    if (!d->pressed)
        return;

    const int pos = d->pick(parentWidget()->mapFromGlobal(e->globalPosition().toPoint()))
                    - d->mouseOffset;
    if (opaqueResize()) {
        moveSplitter(pos);
    } else {
        d->s->setRubberBand(closestLegalPosition(pos));
    }
}
```

**d->pressed** is set in mousePressEvent, so basically when grabMouse() is called the boolean is still false and the function returns.

I don't know if that's expected behavior, but anyway, I fixed it by calling mousePressEvent explicitly through a sendEvent.

```
QMouseEvent ev(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QPointF(0, 0), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
qApp->sendEvent(splitter->handle(1), &ev);
```